# Drupal 7 search form

Tags: 7

I am using drupal's 7 built in search form and need to add placeholder property just for this form, in my template.php my snippet is like below:

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'search_form') {
$form['some_element']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Search');
}
}
```

How can I add this in my module file as I am using built in module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there. Look at the HTML of your search form. The ID is usually search_form. 
This snippet goes into the template.php of your current active theme, replace mytheme with the name of your theme.

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_form') {
    $form['search_form']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Your new placeholder here.');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very similar. Like this

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_form') {
    $form['some_element']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Search');
  }
}
```

Comment: Should I place this in template.php because its not working?Or make a copy of core search form module and make changes in it?

Comment: >Or make a copy of core search form module and make changes in it?

No it's wrong. You should use your own module and don't change contrib and core modules. It should work, try to clear the cache